# Locating a Payload for Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, payload

I was wondering if someone could explain to me where the Payload is for python programming.
I believe I have found the search URL but I am having issues locating where to pass in the parameters too.

This is the website: https://www.axisgis.com/montvillect/

An example value would be 033-016-000

I am hoping to use this method to obtain information from a bunch of these IDs.

I believe the search URL is: https://www.axisgis.com/node/axisapi/tablemodified/MontvilleCT/PropertyID?f=json

If someone could explain this more in depth I would greatly appreciate it.

I am trying to replicate this

```
search_url = "https://newmilfordct.mapgeo.io/api/datasets/properties/search?format=json"


identifier = ID

payload = {
    "page": 1,
    "quickSearch": identifier
}

search_results = requests.post(search_url, payload).json()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the [Referer request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer) with value https://www.axisgis.com/montvillect/.

The following will search the parcel :

```
import requests

parcel="033-016-000"
r = requests.get(f"https://www.axisgis.com/node/axisapi/search/MontvilleCT",
  params= {
    "f": "json",
    "q": parcel
  },
  headers= {
    "Referer": "https://www.axisgis.com/montvillect/"
  })
print(r.json())
```

The following will get all information about a parcel :

```
import requests

parcel="033-016-000"
r = requests.get("https://www.axisgis.com/node/axisapi/parcel/MontvilleCT",
  params = {
    "f":"json",
    "q": parcel,
  },
  headers= {
    "Referer": "https://www.axisgis.com/montvillect/"
  })

print(r.json())
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am just having issues locating where you found the API Link.
I am trying to become more self sufficient in this area and learn where things are found. I know to look in the developers tool and I found the information you located after performing a search on a parcel. 

I took that to a different site but all that was there for parameters with json. Do you have any suggestions in finding parameters or python that will tell you parameters?